# Does "make 3 predictions" sound natural?

Tags: word-usage

"make a prediction" is natural, as it comes from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prediction), how about "make 3 predictions"?

> I'd like to make 3 predictions about the future of New York City, which are about population, housing prices and crime rate. First of all, the population of New York will increase ...

Comment: Is there some reason you think there can't be more than one prediction? In the dictionary link you provide, it shows that it has plural use: (1) *Please don't ask me to make any **predictions** about tomorrow's meeting.* (2) *Her **predictions** turned out to be uncannily accurate.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small whole numbers must be written out: 'three predictions". Apart from that, it sounds natural enough.

Comment: A correct observation by @Jack O'Flaherty.